# Mangopay nodejs sdk

Tags: node.js, mangopay

I'm trying to integrate Mangopay into my nodejs application.

I'm using following sdk.

`https://github.com/larafale/mangopay`

When I'm trying to register new user, I'm getting following error.

`Your authorization do not allow you to access to this information`

I configured the mangopay object using following code.

```
mango = require('mangopay')({
    username: 'client-id',
    password: 'passphrase',
    production: false
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI (and for anyone else finding this), we now have an official Node.js SDK:  https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-nodejs-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly the same request, and it worked find for me with a beautiful 200.

Perhaps you are using your sandbox password instead of your passphrase (generated automatically when you create your sandbox account).